# usb wifi by penguin not working

Tags: wireless

I have a desktop running 14.04 LTS server, Fios router  and a laptop running 14.04 LTS  client
works great I am using Apache2,ftp,squirrelmail  with wired internet   and wifi to laptop     also   iphones and ipads

I want to  move the desktop to the house (a/c)  from the garage 
I purchase a Penguin  USB wifi receiver  model TPE-N150USB   says "works out of the box using lunix"

software setup apt-get install wpasupplicant wireless-tools
  wpa_passphrase "FiOS-6RK0G" "...wpa .."  > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
 /etc/network/interface   add to file

auto wlan0

iface wlan0 static

address 192.168.1.240

wpa-driver  nl80211

wpa-conf   /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

did ifdown wlan0  , ifup wlan0    no errors

ping doesn't work
debug
iwconfig      wlan0    essid off   no ac
ifconfig      wlan0     looks ok

lshw  -c net  wlan0    shows their product and my desktop ip address

dmesg    wlan0 link not ready

wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf  -Dnl80211 -dd     >   sysout

it says

read /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

line 1 start new  network

ssid  hexdump(10)   FiOS-6RK0G

```
    hex numbers  67...
```

psk   hexdump(32)  removed

```
 no numbers
```

prority group 0

id = 0 ssid = FiOS-6RK0G

nl80211: could not add multicast membership for vendor list event: -2 no such directory

rfkill  ...

interface  wlan0 in phy phy0

I cut it off after 15 sec

I plugged their USBcard  into my laptop   it came up in network panel but grayed out so I can't compare

besides my laptop doesnot use wpa_supplicant or passphrase 
but it works with the internal wifi receiver

when I setup my printer,  it found  my ssid    then I hit the "wps" button on my router   it worked
This is what i expected with this card

Penguin helped to get out typo errors  but when it came to big errors they stop responding via email
out of the box to them means you don't need diskwrapper   what ever that is.
I google wpasupplicant  I found their setup proceedure but it was dated 2006
UBUNTU has 9 upgrades since then.

since the server and client have the same software except no graphics how can I use the client setup?
\

Richard

Comment: crossposted at http://ubuntuforums.org/printthread.php?t=2282910&pp=10&page=1